# Where is my gcc.exe?

Tags: windows, gcc

I need to create a simple C application with just a compiler and a text editor. So I installed mingw from [here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/postdownload?source=dlp) I was surprised, when I went to the `bin` folder and there was no `gcc.exe`.
Given that [other people speak about using it](http://bogdan-computer.blogspot.cz/2008/10/use-pspad-with-mingw.html), I suppose it should be there. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you follow [the instructions](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Install_the_MinGW_GCC_Compiler_Suite)?

Comment: You probably forgot to install the compiler when you installed mingw. Open up the MinGW Installation Manager, and make sure mingw32-gcc is checked (else install it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like I shoul've read a little bit more than I did. Downloading and running the installer is only the very beginning of getting gcc.
After installation, `mingw-get.exe` appears in the `/bin` folder. This commands initiates a rather long download process:

```
mingw-get install gcc
```

After this, another downloading command is necessary to get C++ compiler and *make*:

```
mingw-get install gcc g++ mingw32-make
```